# Elasticsearch error when creating index possibly due to module Kuromoji not installed properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, kuromoji, smartcn

I am trying to setup my local environment for a Rails application I just gained access to that uses Elasticsearch 1.3 along with two modules (kuromoji and smartcn)

I have followed instructions to install Elasticsearch along with the modules and when I start elasticsearch I get the following output: (note the plugins line which makes me believe they have been loaded)

```
$ elasticsearch
[2015-07-10 09:56:05,887][INFO ][node                     ] [Rune] version[1.3.9], pid[4364], build[0915c73/2015-02-19T12:34:48Z]
[2015-07-10 09:56:05,887][INFO ][node                     ] [Rune] initializing ...
[2015-07-10 09:56:05,930][INFO ][plugins                  ] [Rune] loaded [analysis-smartcn, analysis-kuromoji], sites []
[2015-07-10 09:56:08,469][INFO ][node                     ] [Rune] initialized
[2015-07-10 09:56:08,469][INFO ][node                     ] [Rune] starting ...
[2015-07-10 09:56:08,577][INFO ][transport                ] [Rune] bound_address {inet[/127.0.0.1:9301]}, publish_address {inet[/127.0.0.1:9301]}
[2015-07-10 09:56:08,596][INFO ][discovery                ] [Rune] elasticsearch_brew/X-HUXjxxT6CtRblL2zANSg
[2015-07-10 09:56:11,611][INFO ][cluster.service          ] [Rune] new_master [Rune][X-HUXjxxT6CtRblL2zANSg][boobooninja.local][inet[/127.0.0.1:9301]], reason: zen-disco-join (elected_as_master)
[2015-07-10 09:56:11,633][INFO ][http                     ] [Rune] bound_address {inet[/127.0.0.1:9201]}, publish_address {inet[/127.0.0.1:9201]}
[2015-07-10 09:56:11,634][INFO ][node                     ] [Rune] started
[2015-07-10 09:56:11,647][INFO ][gateway                  ] [Rune] recovered [0] indices into cluster_state
```

However when I try to run a rake task to index and import the data I get the following error that makes me believe Kuromoji was not loaded or perhaps something else is going on.

```
[!!!] Error when creating the index: Elasticsearch::Transport::Transport::Errors::BadRequest
[400] {"error":"IndexCreationException[[development-activities] failed to create index]; nested: ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException[failed to find token filter type [kuromoji_readingform] for [katakana_readingform]]; nested: NoClassSettingsException[Failed to load class setting [type] with value [kuromoji_readingform]]; nested: ClassNotFoundException[org.elasticsearch.index.analysis.kuromojireadingform.KuromojiReadingformTokenFilterFactory]; ","status":400}
[IMPORT] Done
```

I appreciate any help in determining the issue here.

Answer (score 0):

The message seems about kuromoji plugin. Try to install the plugin.

```
cd path/to/yourelasticsearch
bin/plugin install elasticsearch/elasticsearch-analysis-kuromoji/2.7.0
```

Note that you need to install a proper version of kuromoji plugion depending on the version of elasticsearch you installed. See [here](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-analysis-kuromoji).